# Why is the suru preceding ningen in its te form in the sentence "Kare wa an'na koto o shite ningen to shite shikkakuda"?

Tags: grammar

So yeah why is suru in the te form in this sentence "Kare wa an'na koto o shite ningen to shite shikkakuda"? I'm thinking it is shite to mean "doing" but it isn't followed by iru. Could iru be silent in this case?

Just to clarify I'm not asking about "to shite", I mean the other shite.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are asking about, but the following may help/answer https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21289/45489

Comment: Is the te-form a completely new concept in your studies? Whatever resource you are using will definitely explain the basics of it.

Comment: I'm very familiar with the te form. It can be used to attach an action to a previous action acting as if it's "and" such as "inu wa sushi wo tabete, ie de asobu". But what I don't get is in the sentence "Kare wa an'na koto o shite ningen to shite shikkakuda", the second shite doesn't act normally as a verb since it follows to at least in my understanding. So why is the first suru in its te form? Or is it that the second shite is actually counted as a verb instead of a set phrase "to shite"

Comment: So is it the fact that the sentence ends with da that is the difficulty? You were expecting that it had to be a verb? The "to shite" in the second clause is not a verb, as you noticed.

Comment: @Leebo I mean does te form apply to a condition where it isn't followed by an action? Shikkaku is a noun there's no action happening in the second clause, so I was wondering if te still acts as "and" in cases where the second clause isn't depicting an action.

Comment: It just allows you to attach two clauses, usually because they have some kind of relation to each other, without structuring them as two separate sentences. A clause can end with da, so there's no issue there fundamentally. It doesn't have to be two actions in time. That's just one use of te-form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

て form without いる means "and", it implies that the first part is followed by the second in time and that the first one is the cause of the second one (but not always).

> He doing a thing like that, as a person he is disqualified. -> Because he did a thing like that, he is disqualified as a person

て form is certainly weird. It can have an advervial meaning as in ている but also as a noun-frase when when marked by が or as a clause separator like in this case. Regarding the tense some people say that it is derived from the last verb, but I think context is more important speacially when the 3 meanings kind of get very close to each other.